# InstallShield 2011 Automation Interface StopOnFirstError

Tags: installshield

Does anyone know how I can set a "StopOnFirstError" option on the InstallShield 2011 Automation Interface? I can't seem to find the property on the ISWiProject object. i.e.

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm

but it does seem to be available from the command line and in the MSBuild task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the ISWiRelease Object's BuildErrorCount property. I can use this to at least detect errors.

But it won't stop when the first error is hit and does not provide any details. For that you need to look in the logs.

For more details see

http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpAutoISWiRelease.htm